# Flutter schedule notification using recorded audio

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

Currently I am building an app that requires me to implement a functionality to record audio and use the recorded audio as the sound for a local notification.

I have already set up the notifications using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications), but as far as I am aware, with this plugin you can only specify sounds that have been added to the resource folder before runtime.

This would look like this:

```
const String soundName = 'test_sound.mp3';

NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel id',
        'channel name',
        channelDescription: 'channel description',
        sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(soundName.split('.').first),
      ),
      iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(),
    );
```

Is there a way to record audio files during runtime and use them right away when scheduling a new notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to record the audio file and save it to a location outside of the app. This could, for example, be:

```
// Android
var audio_directory = '/sdcard/Android/media/your_app_name/audio';

// iOS
final Directory dir = await getLibraryDirectory();
var audio_directory = '${join(dir.path, 'Sounds')}/';
```

Then use the file when scheduling a new notification like this:

```
NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        '1',
        '1',
        channelDescription: '1',
        importance: Importance.max,
        sound: UriAndroidNotificationSound(
                'file:///sdcard/Android/media/your_app_name/$soundFile.wav',
               ),
        playSound: vibrationOnly ? false : true,
      ),
      iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
              sound: '$soundFile.aiff',
              presentSound: true,
           ),
);
```